# Allow/block access to a specific path with apache 2.4 failing

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, python, django, ip-blocking

I have a  django website project deployed in an enviroment from AWS Beanstalk. 
I'm trying write configs to apache block access to a specific path (/admin).
I avoid change wsgi.conf file, instead I writing package.config in .ebextensions folder, like following:

```
"/etc/httpd/conf.d/block_admin.conf":
  mode: "000644"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
  <Location /admin>
     <RequireAll>
         Require ip <my_ip>/32
         Require all denied
     </RequireAll>
  </Location>
```

That code is denying all access to "/admin", include from my ip.
I get my ip from services like [what is my ip](https://www.whatismyip.com/).

What am i doing wrong?

PS: My english is a working in progress....

Answer (score 0):

The `<RequireAll>` encloses a group of authorization directives of which none must fail and at least one must succeed in order for the `<RequireAll>` directive to succeed; Thus, RequireAll requires (no pun intended) that "Require all denied" must not fail, which is perhaps not what was desired.

Have you tried just the "Require ip/netmask" by itself?

```
<RequireAll>
  Require ip <my_ip>/32
</RequireAll>
```

The single 'Require ip network/mask' should be sufficient for [RequireAll](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireall) to block access from anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks, but this suggestion did not work. Is there any other? All access keep returning http 403.

Comment: That was a good point, but keeping returning HTTP 403. I tried my home ip too, and keeping failing.